# increase HTTP request connection timeout in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, http-protocols

I'm going to send an array of about 5 millions of records in json format in my spring boot app . is there any way to increase http request timeout in order to prevent from connection timeout?

Comment: Are you sure that this actually does time out?

Comment: some how because I heard timeout duration is 20-60 seconds

Answer (score 7):

For the "default container" that would be:

[`server.tomcat.connection-timeout`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.connection-timeout)

[spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) property.

In this case (JSON body), also:

[`server.tomcat.max-swallow-size`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.tomcat.max-swallow-size)

sounds important.

Also relevant:

```
server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout
// Time to wait for another HTTP request before the connection is closed. When not set the connectionTimeout is used. When set to -1 there will be no timeout.
```

and maybe:

```
server.tomcat.max-connections
```

And:

```
server.tomcat.max-keep-alive-requests
```

For other/reactive containers best: search the linked site for "timeout" :)